# What are some real uses of ERC20 Tokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, economics, use-cases

Hello I am pretty new to the world of crypto and as far as I understand Tokens are basically ERC20 contracts written in the Solidity and deployed on the Ethereum blockchain.

I understand people buying and exchanging these tokens for speculation, but what **goods or services can we buy with tokens? Are there any practical uses? Could you provide some real examples?**

So far to me it all looks like collecting stamps.

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest use cases so far has been to create stable coins. For example: USDC, USDT, BUSD, etc. which are all ERC20 tokens. And yes you can buy things with them, although options are pretty limited at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So would you also agree that most of these buys/sells are just for speculation?

Comment: Most? Probably. All? Definitely not. Many here, myself included, hold a basket of ERC20's as an investment (and farm with them). I believe in a lot of the tech, and the work that many of these DeFi protocols are doing is pretty amazing. For me it's no different than holding a stock long term. It's up to you if you consider that speculation.

Comment: Could you make an example of token which has a project behind and that potentially can have a value associated to a good/service please?

Comment: Value is subjective, but major protocols would be Uniswap, Compound, Aave, SushiSwap, Chainlink, etc...

Comment: Uniswap is a great example: as far as I understand it allows to exchange tokens. What are these tokens good for? Why trading them in the first place? What is the reason of trading them?

Comment: Let's say I have 10 ETH and I want to convert it to USDC. My only option a few years ago was to use an exchange like binance. Now I can do everything from inside my own wallet.